Calculate percentage of overlap between a polygon and raster in Python
I have multiple polygons and a raster of one area. I need to calculate percentage of polygon that overlap the pixel. I need to do this for each pixel.
This is what i have tired
import rasterio
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import osgeo.ogr as ogr
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_raster(path):
    """
    reads the images using rasterio
    
    """
    source = rasterio.open(path)
    return source


def read_polygon(path):
    """
    reads the polygon
    
    """
    shapefile = gpd.read_file(path)
    return shapefile


def fractional_pixel_weights(raster_path, geometry_path):
    """
    Calculate the percent of polygon that overlaps with each pixel in the raster data.
    
    inputs : path to the raster and the polygon
    
    The general idea is that we store the coordinate from the raster for each pixel into a numpy grid.
    We later use this coordinate to create a pixel polygon similar to raster. We do this in a loop for each pixel.
    then we calculate the intersection of the raster polygon and the convex polygon.
    we also taken into consideration that there might be multiple polygons in one pixel.
    
    output : a numpy array with each percent as the values
    """
    raster_image = read_raster(raster_path)
    multi_polygon = read_polygon(geometry_path)
    
    # get the affine transformation from the raster
    gt = raster_image.transform
    
    # Create a numpy grid which has the values as coordinates of the raster.
    xs = np.arange(gt[2], gt[2] +  gt[0] * raster_image.shape[1], gt[0])
    ys = np.arange(gt[5], gt[5] +  gt[4] * raster_image.shape[0], gt[4])
    
    if multi_polygon.crs != raster_image.crs:
        multi_polygon = multi_polygon.to_crs(raster_image.crs)
    # Calculate the area of a single pixel
    pixel_area = abs(gt[0] * gt[4])
    
    # create a numpy array to store the percent values
    overlapping_areas = np.zeros((len(ys)-1, len(xs)-1))
    
    # looping through each polygon
    for index, row in tqdm(multi_polygon.iterrows(), total=len(multi_polygon)):
        single_polygon = row['geometry']
        
        #convert the polygon as ogr class which was previously shapely class 
        geom_ogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(single_polygon.wkt)
        
        # we loop through the numpy array and store the coordinate to convert the pixel into polygon
        for ix in range(len(xs)-1):
            xmin = xs[ix]
            xmax = xs[ix + 1]
            for iy in range(len(ys)-1):
                ymax = ys[iy]
                ymin = ys[iy + 1]
                
                #create a 10x10 m polygon based on the coordinate of the pixel.
                coords_wkt = "POLYGON ((" + str(xmin) + ' ' + str(ymax) + ', ' + str(xmax) + ' ' + str(ymax) + ', ' + str(xmax) + ' ' + str(ymin) + ', ' + str(xmin) + ' ' + str(ymin) + ', ' + str(xmin) + ' ' + str(ymax) + "))"
                poly_cell = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(coords_wkt)
                # Calculate how much the polygon intersect the pixel polygon 
                intersection = poly_cell.Intersection(geom_ogr).Area()
                overlapping_areas[iy, ix] += intersection  # Accumulate overlapping areas
                overlapping_areas[iy, ix] = min(overlapping_areas[iy, ix], pixel_area)
                
    

    # Calculate fractional intersection
    fraction_intersected = np.clip((overlapping_areas / pixel_area) * 100, 0, 100)

    return fraction_intersected

def save_as_raster(input_raster_path, grid, output_raster_path):
    """
    Save the grid as raster
    
    input: raster which was used to calculate the percentage, 
    the output grid which has the percent values
    path to save the file
    
    output: a raster file which contains the precent as pixel value
    """
    with rasterio.open(input_raster_path) as src:
        # Get metadata from source raster
        meta = src.meta.copy()

        # Update the metadata to reflect the number of layers
        meta.update(dtype=rasterio.float32, count=1)

        # Write output raster
        with rasterio.open(output_raster_path, 'w', **meta) as dst:
            dst.write(grid.astype(rasterio.float32), 1) 

There are two problem with this. In areas where there are no polygon that values are higher than the area where there is pixel. The second problem is that in there are pixel is overlapped by the polygon but in the result these pixel are missing.
example.


What are the dimensions/pixel count of your raster? Do you want to output as a raster, where the pixel value is the polygon overlap proportion?

The dimension is width:142, height 201. Yes the output's pixel value is the polygon overlap proportion

I hope I understood your problem correctly. I created this sample raster and polygons overlapping it:

This function uses shapely, rasterio, geopandas, and numpy just like your approach:
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import bounds
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

def calculate_overlap_percentage(raster_path, shapefile_path, output_raster_path):
    gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

    with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
        raster_meta = src.meta.copy()
        transform = src.transform
        
        # Create an array to store overlap percentages
        overlap_array = np.zeros((src.height, src.width), dtype=np.float32)
        
        # Iterate over the grid
        for row in range(src.height):
            for col in range(src.width):
                # Get the pixel bounds as shapely box
                pixel_bounds = bounds(
                    rasterio.windows.Window(col, row, 1, 1), transform
                )
                pixel_polygon = box(*pixel_bounds)
                
                # Calc intersection
                overlap_area = 0
                for geom in gdf.geometry:
                    intersection = pixel_polygon.intersection(geom)
                    overlap_area += intersection.area
                
                # Calc % (intersection area / pixel area)
                pixel_area = pixel_polygon.area
                overlap_percentage = (overlap_area / pixel_area) * 100 if pixel_area > 0 else 0
                
                overlap_array[row, col] = overlap_percentage
        
        with rasterio.open(output_raster_path, 'w', **raster_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(overlap_array, 1)


calculate_overlap_percentage(
    raster_path=r"C:\Daten\test_raster.tif",
    shapefile_path=r"C:\Daten\test_polygon.shp",
    output_raster_path=r"C:\Daten\output.tif"
)

The resulting raster has the percentage of overlap between the respective pixel and the polygons as pixel values. Here is the result:

Note, that you can have higher values then 100 if the polygons are overlapping each other. If you want to cap the values at 100, you could either add that condition in the code or do a preprocessing of the polygon data (dissolve):

